# Opposite of White Bear principle?

Tags: memory, terminology, working-memory, long-term-memory

Is there any phrase/term to describe the opposite of [White Bear principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironic_process_theory) (also known as ironic process principle)? 
I'm looking for a word to describe the process where something eludes you the more you try to think of it (or remember it). I think I may have come across a term to describe this phenomenon but I'm not sure if such a phrase/term exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
**[Over-thinking](http://www.news.ucsb.edu/2013/013593/overthinking-can-be-detrimental-human-performance)**

**Background**
**[Unconscious recall of information](https://qz.com/113458/want-to-remember-something-forget-it/)** can be more effective than conscious recall of that same information. Disruption of the activity of the **[dorsolateral prefrontal cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsolateral_prefrontal_cortex)** (by TMS) improved image-recall in healthy subjects (source: [UC Santa Barbara](http://www.news.ucsb.edu/2013/013593/overthinking-can-be-detrimental-human-performance)). The dorsolateral prefrontal cortex is associated with executive functions including working memory and selective attention [(Lehner *et al*., 2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780128001059). The effect over paying too much attention in an attempt to remember something has been referred to as [over-thinking](https://qz.com/113458/want-to-remember-something-forget-it/).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lehner *et al*., *Genomics, Circuits, and Pathways in Clinical Neuropsychiatry*, 1<sup>st</sup> ed. Elsevier (2016)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780128001059)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I must admit I was hoping for a more interesting term for it!

Comment: Is it the same with [rumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumination_(psychology))?